# How to remap the Ctrl+Click "Go To Definition" short-key in the Productivity Power Tools (or maybe ReSharper)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper, productivity-power-tools

I love the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) extension for visual studio, however it has added the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Click "Go To Definition" functionality, which is great and all, but my workflow makes me use the functionality when I don't want it.

When I want to copy something, I start marking some text, still holding down the mouse button, hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and then release the mouse button. The tool acknowledges this as a Go To Definition click, and I usually end up in the definition of String or whatever. I know I could just release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button prior to the mouse-button; however, I have a hard time reconditioning myself from a habit I have had since forever.

Is there a way to remap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click Go To Definition functionality, say, to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Click? I know I can deactivate it by going to "Tools>Options>Productivity Power Tools>All Extensions"; however, I don't want to lose the functionality just make it work as I want it.

**Edits:**

- This might be a [ReSharper issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-290402).
- [This post](http://www.jaylee.org/post/2010/06/13/VS2010-How-to-disable-the-Power-Tools-Ctrl2bClick-Go-to-Definition.aspx) discusses something similar

Comment: It would help if you determined which plug-in was causing it.  If you have Resharper, turn off the feature and see if it's still there.

Comment: did you ever find a way of doing this? i experience the same thing as i use ctrl+drag to copy&paste a lot

Comment: Thank you for asking this question. This "going to definition" has been bugging me due to my CTRL+C -> CTRL+V finger behviour. I alway end up pasting a varible name or object type into the middle of the object type declaration and this makes me curse out loud!

I generally use "Right-Click" -> "Go To Definition" when I actually intend to go to it, so removal of this little annoyance is welcome by me.

Comment: I'd love a solution for this as well. My workflow is that CTRL+Mouseclick should select the whole word under the mouse. So I really like to remap the PPT function to CTRL+SHIFT+Click.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try going to `ReSharper | Options -> Environment | Search & Navigation` and turning off `Go to declaration on <Control + Left click> in editor`.

Comment: ReSharper and the Productivity Power Tools (PPT) extension both added the same functionality. I turned it of in PPT, but it still persisted. Your suggestion removed it entirely, thanks. However, I really wanted to change the key combination not disable it. If no better answer comes within a day or two, I'll accept yours.

Comment: In my case, I wanted ReSharper's version, but PPT was overriding it. I turned off ReSharper's implementation, then turned off PPT's version, then restarted VS. Finally, I turned ReSharper's implementation back on. This worked for me.

Answer (score 27):

I don't have ReSharper. But I was able to turn this off in Visual Studio 2012. I found it in Tools - Options - Productivity Power Tools - Ctrl+Click Go To Definition.

Comment: if you have PPT and resharper you need to turn off both settings

Comment: Thank you. This has been irking me since upgrading to 2012. There will now be no more "I didn't effing ask to go to definition!" in my office. :)

Comment: I still use F12 for that. CTRL + Click is anoying while navigating with the mouse and pasting... +1 for U!

Answer (score 9):

Try menu *Tools* → *Options* → *Productivity Power Tools* (left menu) → Turn it off where it says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Click Go To Definition on your right side.

[image]