# How do I turn off or remap ctrl + left click in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, typescript, key-bindings, visual-studio-code

Does anyone know how I can turn off or remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + left click in Visual Studio Code?  I seem to have the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key depressed when selecting text with my mouse to copy about 20% of the time, and it is really annoying to navigate to another file in the middle of it.

[Visual Studio Code - Key Bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/keybindings)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12137953/how-to-remap-the-ctrlclick-go-to-definition-short-key-in-the-productivity-pow

Comment: @E.Moffat that's for visual studio—not visual studio code.

Comment: @DavidSherret Totally missed that. My mistake!

Comment: @E.Moffat it's an easy mistake to make that happens all the time. It's slightly annoying how similarly named the two applications are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a quick peek at the *VS Code* keyboard shortcuts documentation and found a list of [accepted keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y638T.png).

[image]

Usually you would go to **File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts** and add your custom bindings like so:

(this is the keybindings.json file found @ C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Code\User)

```
// Place your key bindings in this file to overwrite the defaults
[
    { "key": "f8",                    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.build" },
    { "key": "ctrl+[mouse button]",   "command": "cursorWordLeft",
                                         "when": "editorTextFocus" }
]
```

But unfortunately, according to the documentation, mouse rebinding seems unsupported.

That being said VS Code is an open source project so you could always propose this feature or pitch in and see what you can do!

Here's the config file for the editor.
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/blob/master/src/vs/editor/common/config/config.ts

Comment: Thanks!  Too bad it isn't supported. Maybe if I get time I'll attempt to add it.

Comment: It should also be worth noting that VIsual Studio Code will operate differently depending on what language and/or extensions are installed and active